# React Api Call with a File as Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, endpoint, fetch-api

I have this handler to make api calls to an endpoint:

```
handleFileChange(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(apiAddress)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json()
    }).then( (res)  => {
      this.props.onFileChange(JSON.stringify(res));
  });
}
```

And i would like send a file as part of the requests like this:

```
render(){
  getScene();
  return (
    <form>
     <input type='file' name='uploaded_file' />
     <button onClick={this.handleFileChange}>Upload</button>
   </form>
  )
}
```

How can it do that with the file added in that form?

Answer (score 1):

This is just as simple as POSTing the File to the API:

```
handleFileChange(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let fileInput = document.getElementsByName("uploaded_file")[0];
  fetch('/yourEndpoint', {
    method: 'POST'
    body: fileInput.files[0] // This is your file object
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": fileInput.files[0].type // this is the MIME type of the data *
    },
  }).then(
    response => response.json()
  ).then( res => {
    this.props.onFileChange(JSON.stringify(res))
  });
}
```

* note, however, that this is generated from the file extension, so it can easily be spoofed

Comment: I don't need to specify anything else? Like content type or something?

Comment: Your browser should handle this for you.

Comment: Is not doing it. And acording to the network console the conten type is text/plain and  I'm geting a 404. The api is also mine, built with Spark, so maybe the problem is something else. But I know is working by using a simple form in plain html.

Comment: Yes, using react im getting a 404. But using a basic form it works.

Comment: Is the server crashing when you post to it this way? Because, a 404 is for when the requested resource can't be located, which shouldn't happen, if the url is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168857/discussion-between-xhark-and-luca).

Comment: Im getting this message in my spark server: The requested route [/scene] has not been mapped in Spark. But it keep working after that.